# C# arrays scope

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# for job reasons and I have knowledge in C and C++ so I'm trying to skip as much theory as I can.
I'm having a hard time figuring out why I cannot define arrays outside Main function. If I do this inside Main, It works.

I have tryed some codes from online tutorials of super-basic array sintax; and somehow I can't make them work.

Example:

```
int [] ages;
   ages= new int[2];
   ages [0] = 20; ---> until I fill the array.
```

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work? In the one above, out of context, there is nothing wrong in it

Comment: a statement must be enclosed inside a method, so if the second and the third lines are not within a method there will be a compilation error. alternatively, you can do `int[] ages = new int[2];` in one line at the class level which should be fine.

Comment: "I'm trying to skip as much theory as I can" You're asking for a world of trouble then. C# is _not_ an extension of C or C++ - it just uses a LOT of the same syntax. C# is a _managed_ language, meaning that you can't use the same memory tricks (like manipulating arrays) that are prevalent in C and C++.  You also can't have code (other than member initialization) outside of class members.

Comment: *I'm trying to skip as much theory as I can.* And the obvious consequence is... you will be in for a world of surprises if you think a C, C++ background will let you skip most of C#'s theory...

Comment: Or, following the @Aominè thoughts, you can write _int[] ages = new int[2] {20,0};_ initializing the array with a specific value

Comment: Having originally learned C++/handling naked pointers/arrays and later C#, I can confirm the differences are to big. I mean you can theoretically go to unmanaged code. But doing that looses you 75% of the Advantages that C#/.NET offers, while only adding the exact problems that C# tried to avoid by design.

Comment: Note that c++ behaves identical in similar case of defining fields of a class...

Answer (score 4):

A word of advice, please do not skip the `C#` theoretical information as it's very important. By reading the theory side of a programming language you further familiarise your self with the rules in terms of the do's and don'ts. You also gain a better knowledge of how the language works and how it differs from your background of `C` and `C++`.

Had you said you came from a Java background that would have made more sense as they're quite similar though they differ in some areas.

In C# you cannot declare a statement like this:

```
ages = new int[2];
ages [0] = 20;
```

at the class level. **Rather, it must be encapsulated in a method**. However, you can declare `int[] ages = new int[2];` at the class level without a compilation error.

Lastly, but not least the [C# Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/) is a good place to start as it will help further familiarise yourself with the language.

Comment: Agreed, Java is lightyears closer to C#/.NET then native C++. You could go as far as saying .NET is a improovemnet/continuiation of Java's basic ideas. And you would not be totally wrong.

Comment: You can also declare `int[] ages = new int[] { 20, 30 };` by using an array initializer outside of a method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to declare the array in the Program class, and you weren't able to reference it in your static Main method. In **static** methods, you can only reference **static**.

```
class Program
{
    static int[] staticFieldArray = new int[10];
    int[] instanceFieldArray = new int[10];

    static void Main()
    {
        staticFieldArray[0] = 10; //compiles fine, you can reference the static from static.
        instanceFieldArray[0] = 10; //comiple error, cant reference instance field from static method.
    }
}
```